# convert a text to str with ''' '''

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code

```
with open('txt.txt', 'r') as f:
    logs = f.read()
    print(logs)
```

output:

```
[09-06-2022 15:23:59] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)', None, ['Backtrace:', '\tOrdinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]', '\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]', '\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]', '\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]', '']), 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "maingui.py", line 94, in run\n  File "maingui.py", line 249, in <lambda>\n  File "maingui.py", line 361, in parser\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response\nselenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)\nStacktrace:\nBacktrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]\n\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]\n\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]\n\n')
```

the output i needed

```
[09-06-2022 15:23:59] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}
      (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)', None, ['Backtrace:', '        Ordinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]', '       Ordinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]', '   Ordinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]', '  Ordinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]', '       Ordinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]', '        Ordinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]', '        GetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]', ' GetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]', '      GetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]', '       GetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]', '  Ordinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]', '       Ordinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]', '       BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]', '    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]', '    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]', '']), 'Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "maingui.py", line 94, in run
      File "maingui.py", line 249, in <lambda>
      File "maingui.py", line 361, in parser
      File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
      File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
      File "selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}
      (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)
    Stacktrace:
    Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]
            Ordinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]
            Ordinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]
            Ordinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]
            Ordinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]
            Ordinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]
            Ordinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]
            Ordinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]
            Ordinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]
            Ordinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]
            Ordinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]
            Ordinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]
            Ordinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]
            Ordinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]
            Ordinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]
            RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]
            RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]
    
    ')
```

its code:

```
x = '''[09-06-2022 15:23:59] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)', None, ['Backtrace:', '\tOrdinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]', '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]', '\tOrdinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]', '\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]', '\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]', '\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]', '']), 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "maingui.py", line 94, in run\n  File "maingui.py", line 249, in <lambda>\n  File "maingui.py", line 361, in parser\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute\n  File "selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response\nselenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.63)\nStacktrace:\nBacktrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x0115A8E3+2402531]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010EB011+1945617]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FDC748+837448]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x01009330+1020720]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010095CB+1021387]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010363B2+1205170]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010242F4+1131252]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010346C2+1197762]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010240C6+1130694]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFE676+976502]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00FFF586+980358]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013CBC42+2511938]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x013BED6F+2458991]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F31AA+575914]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x011F1FA6+571302]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F1DEB+1973739]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6778+1992568]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010F6865+1992805]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x010FFA41+2030145]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA6739+25]\n\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FEF+1215]\n\tRtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77CA8FBD+1165]\n\n')'''
print(x)
```

so i was wondering if there is anyway to convert the text to a str with '''{content}''' so that it can print the contents of the file properly.

Comment: If the text doesn't already have line breaks in it, you'll have to add them yourself. That won't be trivial.

Comment: @MarkRansom the text seem to have line breaks. @Jishnu You need to do `print(logs.decode())` since f.read() returns bytes and not string

Comment: getting  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'@SembeiNorimaki
and f.read() returned a str, type(logs) --> <class 'str'>

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki no, it has an occasional multi-character sequence that *resembles* a line break.

Comment: i tried adding them but somehow the '\n' or any other escape character it doesn't print them, it just prints it raw 
output: `[09-06-2022 15:23:59]\n(<class'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>\n`
@MarkRansom

Comment: when you convert more complex object to string then it may create string useful for debuging - and it may shows `\n` `\t`, unicode chars, etc. in this string. And it can convert `\n` to `\\n` to show it. You may have to convert it back from `\\n` to `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it converts more complex object to string then it may try to create string useful for debuging (or useful to recreate original object from string) - and it may need to shows `\n`, `\t`, `unicode chars`, etc. in this string.

And it can convert `\n` to `\\n` to show it - because single `\` has special meaning in string and it has to use double `\\` to put normal `\` in string. The same problem is with `\t`.

You may have to convert it back from `\\n` to `\n` (and from `\\t` to `\t`)

```
print( logs.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\t', '\t') )
```

or using `raw-string` - `r'\n'` and `r'\t'`

```
print( logs.replace(r'\n', '\n').replace(r'\t', '\t') )
```

Comment: @Jishnu so now the question is how `r'\n'` got into your file in the first place?  A better plan is to fix it at the source rather than band-aiding it as this answer suggests.

Comment: these are tracebacks from selenium i just saved it into a file for simple logging, but the text themselves doesn't seem to have any `//n` in them (Link: https://pastebin.com/hBPDfy4Z) as you can see there is no `//n` so i think its read() which is reading it as raw (`r'error\n...'`) @MarkRansom

Comment: @Jishnu the code you showed in the question would not have produced that result.

Comment: @Jishnu problem can be when you write data in file and @MarkRansom suggests to fix problem when you write data. But I'm not sure if problem is because you convert data to  string when you write it  or `selenium` uses `str()` to display error and this makes problem.

Comment: so you would have to use `replace()` when you write it. `str(n).replace(...).replace(...)` - it can be the easiest method to resolve problem. Trying to convert `n` to string in different way can be too complex.

Comment: I was using the pyqt thread signals to get the error from selenium and apparently it returned a tuple which had `(error msg, exception, traceback)` in it so when i did `tuple[2]` and it wrote the error properly into the file without `\n` or `\t` also it worked when i did `str(n).replace(..)` too but i found it more convenient to just use `tuple[2]` @furas and @MarkRansom thanks for the help and spending time to solve the issue, now it works as excepted

Comment: @Jishnu congratulations on finding your root cause!  Your explanation makes perfect sense; when you call `str()` on a `tuple`, it calls `repr()` on each element.  And for strings that will convert the one-character newline to a two-character `\n` sequence.